# R Plotly - change names of axis in heatmap

Tags: rstudio, heatmap, plotly

I don't know how to change names of axis in my heatmap. This is my example code:

```
 p <- plot_ly(x = XXX, y =  YYY, z = ZZZ, type = "heatmap")
 p
```

And I wont to my axis different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example (you did not provide a reproducible example) that will give you x/y labels and a title

```
x <- list(
    title = "x Axis"
)
y <- list(
    title = "y Axis"
)
plot_ly(z = volcano, colorscale = "Hot", type = "heatmap") %>% layout(title = "Hello", xaxis = x, yaxis = y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try it and unfortunately I have error: Error in layout(., title = "Hello", xaxis = x, yaxis = y) : 
  unused arguments (title = "Hello", xaxis = x, yaxis = y)

Comment: that't why you need to add your dataset to your post; this example should work with your data so you must do something else wrong

Comment: Hello MLavoie, I try even original code which you wrote above and I get normal heatmap but when I try the second part of code i get error.

Comment: I have noticed plotly might sometime gives error when It should not. I am using plotly_2.0.16. But the example in my answer works on my computer.....and what is the error you getting?

Comment: I don't know if it might explain, but I am using the R console (not R studio)

Comment: I use R studio and I get nice plot but my problem is even worse.  I can't change names of axis in any of my plots. I receives dotplot, barplot and heatmap in plotly but I cant change names of axis and title. Error is: `in layout(., title = "Hello", xaxis = x, yaxis = y) : unused arguments (title = "Hello", xaxis = x, yaxis = y)`. It is the same on every single plot. I use information from [link](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#Layout_and_layout_style_objects)

Comment: do you have the latest plotly version?

Comment: Thank you very much for help MLavoie. I just update my plotly package and it works perfect.